# Angular 2 angular-cli AOT declare abstract class in module?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to get AOT compilation setup with angular-cli. I've got a directive that inherits from an abstract class, and I'm getting an error during compilation that angular can't determine what module the abstract class belongs to. I can't add it to the declarations array of the NgModule, so what's the right way to go about this? My code structure looks like this,

```
//...imports
export abstract class TutorialDirective  {
    //...base class logic
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[tut]',
    exportAs: 'tut'
})
export class DefaultTutorialDirective extends TutorialDirective {
    //...calls into the base class for some shared stuff.
}
```

Error looks like this

```
ERROR in Cannot determine the module for class TutorialDirective in /test-app/src/app/tutorial/directive/tutorial.directive.ts!
```

My AppModule:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { TutorialService } from './tutorial/tutorial.service';
import { TutorialDirective, DefaultTutorialDirective } from './tutorial/directive/tutorial.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DefaultTutorialDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [TutorialService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Ok after some debugging, if I make it not abstract and add it to declarations it works. Does this mean I can't mark a class as abstract? That doesn't seem right...

Comment: Add the code for your module  app.module.ts

Comment: @Aravind ok. I cannot add the TutorialDirective to the declarations array. Just letting you know.

Comment: Ok, if I make it not abstract and add it to declarations it works. Does this mean I can't mark a class as abstract? That doesn't seem right...

Comment: I didnt mean the declarations array. I meant about your application's module specification code

Comment: @Aravind I've posted that.

Comment: I have the same problem here. Would be interested to know the right solution. Is it not possible to make abstract classes?

Comment: There's an issue raised for this on the [Angular Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13590)

Answer (score 14):

Remove the @Component decorator from the abstract class, replacing it with an @Injectable() decorator.

Comment: This seems like the correct solution to me. You shouldn't need the decorator since each class implementing the abstract class will have its own decorator. Once the decorator is removed for the abstract class you won't need to put it in your ngModule declarations as it's just a normal typescript import at this point.

Comment: I also had to add @Injectable() in place of @Component to get this working

Comment: IMO this solution makes the most sense ; since it's abstract, it can't really be considered what angular defines as a component.

Comment: I've got the same exact issue as the OP and my abstract class doesn't have a `Component` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. It is true that if you create a abstract class and try using it as a directive controller, it will not work the reason is here at the [**documentation**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html)

Highlighted part of the documentation as below [image]

When ever you create a directive the **Angular creates a new instance of the directive's controller class**. When you use an abstract class, you cannot have instance for it and hence it fails in your case

Comment: I have an implementing class that just inherits from the base class which is the instance angular would be creating, not the abstract one. This all works if I use JIT, but not AOT. I'm not sure that's it.